# get data from function angularJS

Tags: angularjs

i will get data from function, in case this my code..

```
 var urlServer = 'http://localhost:2205/inventoryApp/server/'; 
  $scope.getReport = function() {
    $http.get( urlServer + 'transaksi.php?action=getreport').success(function(data) {
      $scope.reports = data;
      // console.log($scope.reports.tanggal);
      // if i run this console (inside function) the data is showing in console log
    });        
  };

  $scope.getReport();
  console.log($scope.reports);
 //this console log get undefined
```

and i get undefined in my console log..

thanks before :)

Comment: So you should check if your http request just fails using `.error()`. (Beware, both, `.success` and `.error` are deprecated)

Comment: my http request is success, i show data in my view(template) no error and show the data

Comment: You have to write the `console.log(data)` in side your callback

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs synchronously, your request runs asynchronous, so this should work:

```
var urlServer = 'http://localhost:2205/inventoryApp/server/'; 
  $scope.getReport = function() {
    $http.get( urlServer + 'transaksi.php?action=getreport').success(function(data) {
      $scope.reports = data;
      // console.log($scope.reports.tanggal);
      // if i run this console (inside function) the data is showing in console log
console.log($scope.reports);
    });        
  };

  $scope.getReport();

window.setTimeout(function()
{
    console.log('data should be available now', $scope.reports);
}, 5000);
```

You just have to wait until your request is finished before you can display its response. :-)

For example, after a few seconds, your data should be available. To make this clean, use promises as you can see here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: if console.log inside function absoluty work... but if outside get unifed.. so i ask this question

Comment: Its not `undefined` in the outside. Its just `undefined` when you try to output it. I will update my answer.

Comment: i see.. the data need interval to already set. thanks very much thomas :)

Answer (score 1):

console is executed before executing get service. try to use .then() function and console in it.